# How to prevent escaped newlines in split string (python)

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a script that will convert a CSV to JSON.
One of my spreadsheet cells contains '<,>' delimited strings. I'd like to convert this to a list. I have the following line in my script handling that cell:

```
quest["preMessages"] = [x.strip() for x in row["preMessages"].split('<,>')]
```

where row["preMessages"] represents the text in the cell.

It mostly works except for one case where my cell input is the following:

```
I'm receiving orders from headquarters!<,>
<THE_COMPANY> assigns tasks to the <SHIP_NAME> from time to time. \n\n Best to complete them as soon as possible before they take corrective measures.
```

My output is:

```
"preMessages": [
"I'm receiving orders from headquarters!", 
"<THE_COMPANY> assigns tasks to the <SHIP_NAME> from time to time.\\n\\n Best to complete them as soon as possible before they take corrective measures."
],
```

The problem is the newlines in the middle. I want them to stay as non-escaped newlines. When I print row["preMessages"] right before this line, it looks normal like it did in the spreadsheet.

Even when I remove the call to strip() the problem persists so it must be the split. But I provided my own delimiter so I'm not sure why it's messing with the new lines.

How can I keep my newlines intact?

Comment: nothing wrong with that, it's inside a quoted string so it's `\\n` instead of `\n` but the value is only a single backslash

Comment: but when i ingest it into my app it displays as a string instead of actually processing the newline. i'd like the json that comes out of the script to not need further processing in the app. perhaps i'm missing something obvious?

Comment: then replace `\\n` with `\n`